# Read from console XCode iOS app (not command line app)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I want to read inputs from debug console, to create commands that will be read by the app in order to get more control in my app. For example I want to send commands like:

```
addCoins 200
```

and my app should read this line and parse it to call the function:

```
addCoins(amount: 200)
```

In the didViewLoad I tried to create an async function and inside read console to know if the user has written some commands but it is not working.

I am not sure if it is possible at all.

My code inside the viewDidLoad is:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
queue.async {

    let command = readLine(strippingNewline: true)

    if command != nil {

        //parse command to do something
        print("\(command)!")

    }      

}
```

I want to read the commands as following:

[image]

Comment: The iOS simulator opens `/dev/null` for `stdin`.  I don't think you can use `readLine` the way you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application can not read your console input if it's an iOS app. You can certainly use debugging features to read information during runtime.

You might not need this but, in the lldb debugger, you can set up breakpoints and use basic commands to read and modify some information at runtime. Apple has a comprehensive tutorial on Xcode debugging. [Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html) You can also look at lldb tutorial here. [lldb tutorial](https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/)